# Non-cumbersome respiration sensor for sleep study?

Tags: respiration, electrocardiography

I'm working on a project where I collect ECG signal from multiple volunteers, derive ECG derived respiration(EDR) from the timestamped ECG signal and calculate the cross correlation between EDR and Respiration signals collected from [NeuLog](https://neulog.com/respiration-monitor-belt/) device which is treated as reference respiration signal. The problem is that the NeuLog moniter, although widely in use for monitoring respiration, is very cumbersome and uncomfortable for the volunteers to wear and restricts breathing. Is there any alternative respiration monitering devices which doesn't have to be strapped around the chest and less cumbersome to wear?

The following are the other requirements.

1. Respiration signal should be time stamped(to synchronize with ECG signal).
2. Minimum Sampling rate of atleast 5sps.
3. Should collect data offline for atleast 10 hours in single charge of the battery.

I found [this](http://www.masimo.com/rra/) device which seems to be more comfortable than NeuLog but it is not clear whether it measures only respiration rate or can also log Respiration signals along with timestamps.

If anyone knows any alternative products meeting the above requirements, please do share the details.